# Use of "due to"

Tags: sentence-construction

Using "due to" twice in the following sentences is not good. Can someone suggest a way to write the second sentence without using "due to"?

> In this work, aerodynamic losses **due to** blade profile and secondary
>   flows is investigated. The results show that losses **due to** them are
>   lower for proposed design.

("Them" in the last sentence = blade profile loss and secondary flow loss)

Comment: "show that these losses are lower"... and you need a "the" before proposed design

Comment: In the first sentence, the subject _losses_ is plural and should take the plural verb.

Comment: Did you try looking this up in a [thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/due%20to?s=t)?

Comment: Synonyms for *due to* include *caused by*, *because of*, and *from*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'because of' instead of *due to*, but these phrases are unnecessary in the sentence.  If you say *these losses* or *the said losses,* it will mean the losses you have mentioned earlier.

Also, you should use *are* instead of *is* after 'flows' and add 'the' in front of 'proposed design', as commented by Catija and P.E. Dant.